# How can I select elements in a column based on a priority list in python?

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have a column that contains multiple values in each row. I am trying to write a function to select just one value of each row based on a priority list, so that is reduced just to one value. I am using python.

my column looks like this:

```
Green&Yellow
Yellow
Blue&Orange
Orange&Green
Purple&Green
Purple
Yellow&Purple
Green
```

My priority list is:

```
Priority_list = [Green, Orange, Blue, Purple, Yellow ]
```

The desired output would be:

```
Green
Yellow
Orange
Green
Green
Purple
Purple
Green
```

The code should be something like this:

```
def select_color(value):

    color = value.split('&')
    if len(color) > 1:
        my_color = first color found in list
    else:
        my_color = color

    return my_color
```

I can't find the way to select the first value appearing in the priority list.

Thanks a lot,

Rachael

Comment: Would you be able to provide a sample dataframe for us to see what it looks like?

Answer (score 1):

More simple you can try:

```
import re
c = ["Green&Yellow","Yellow","Blue&Orange","Orange&Green","Purple&Green","Purple","Yellow&Purple","Green"]
p = ["Green", "Orange", "Blue", "Purple", "Yellow" ]
[[re.findall('(?i)(' + v + ').*?', x) for v in p if re.findall('(?i)(' + v + ').*?', x)][0][0] for x in c]
```

the results:

```
['Green', 'Yellow', 'Orange', 'Green', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Purple', 'Green']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was really useful, I wrote the function with this piece of code.

Comment: @B Gees , could you please explain the for loop in the list comprehension?

Answer (score 0):

```
# list = Global list of colors that you want
# color = string col1&col2&col3...
def select_color(list, color):
    color_list = color.split('&')
    for col in color_list:
        if col in list:
            return col
    return
```

if you get None as return value that means that the color is not found

Comment: All Color are in the list, what I want to know is what color is first in the priority list

Answer (score 0):

**If all your color in priority_list then below code will help you**

```
priority_list = [Green, Orange, Blue, Purple, Yellow ]

def select_color(value):

    color = value.split('&')
    if len(color) == 1:
        return color[0]
    else:
        for pcolor in priority_list:
            if pcolor in color :
                return pcolor;
```